# how to control orders of charts in highcharts combination charts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts to create a combined chart including a pie chart and a bubble chart.

```
series: [
            {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Total consumption',
                data: [
                    {name: 'CE', y: 20},
                    {name: 'RR', y: 20},
                    {name: 'AC', y: 20},
                    {name: 'AE', y: 20}
                ],
                //center: [400, 200],
                align: 'center',
                //size: 200,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'bubble',
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [
                    {x: 5, y: 9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany', zIndex: 1},
                    {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium', zIndex: 1}

                ],
                zIndex: 9
            }
        ],
```

But how could I put the bubble chart on top of the pie chart? No matter how I set the zIndex, the pie chart is always on top of the bigger bubble.

Comment: please use http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each type the zIndex to work as supposed

```
series: [
        {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total consumption',
            data: [
                {name: 'CE', y: 20},
                {name: 'RR', y: 20},
                {name: 'AC', y: 20},
                {name: 'AE', y: 20}
            ],
            zIndex: 2,
            //center: [400, 200],
            align: 'center',
            //size: 200,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'bubble',
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [
                {x: 5, y: 9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany', zIndex: 1},
                {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium', zIndex: 1}

            ],
            zIndex: 9
        }
    ]
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rds5wypc/)

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. Just a reminder that the color scheme may mess up your eyes.